# discovery of ec2 on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Here is my elasticsearch configuration (elasticsearch.yml file.

```
**cluster:
  name: demo.elasticsearch.com

node:
  name: node1

discovery:

type: ec2

ec2:

groups: elastic-search

host_type: private_dns

ping_timeout: 5s

gateway:

type: s3

s3:

bucket: elastic-search-demo

cloud:

aws:

access_key: A*************4M

secret_key: sT********************lmn8

region: us-east-1**
```

I installed elastic search and cloud-aws plugin and I have two instances in the same **aws account** in **us-east-1d** with security group **elastic-search**. Security group are configured with **9300-9400 ports** enabled for **TCP connection**.

When I start elastic search on one instance, it elect itself as a master, things are going as desired upto here. **But when I start elastic search on another instance, it could not discover first ec2 instance and elect itself as a master**.

I did lots of googling but with no help. Please get me out of the problem.

Comment: did you get this fixed?

Answer (score 2):

It may be the ports that are causing the problem. Elasticsearch binds to port 9200 and 9300 by default.  If you add those rules to your security group you should be set.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would advise to simplify the YAML by using the full namespaces.

Second, You should set the region as:
**cloud.aws.region: us-east-1**

Following is my **elasticsearch.yml** as an example:

```
cluster.name: elastic-search-test

node.name: node-1

cloud.aws.access_key: *******

cloud.aws.secret_key: *******

cloud.aws.region: us-west-2

discovery.type: ec2

discovery.ec2.groups: security-group-name

gateway.type: s3

gateway.s3.bucket: elasticsearch-bucket-name
```